# Geometry to BufferGeometry, three.js, Float32Array, and Uint32Array

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry

I have a BufferGeometry object and a three.js script which processes this object and an input Buffered object.

It looks like this:

```
"geometries": [{
    "uuid": "EE890F4D-C1F6-43BD-ACD3-F32884E81768",
    "data": {
        "attributes": {
            "position": {
                "array": "4NXSPSuyLD2jdag/AaTWPXj0Oj2kpao/Tx7WPWYZPT3ulKo/C5rWPbr/Pj26oKo/CrnSPUbPLT1X\r\nYKg/5D3IPRNrRz3ABKo/iC/TPUIbKj12bKg/hkDJPWrnSj3a/qk/Ro7JPVL4Rz2H/qk/bAqfPe4n\r\n",
                "itemSize": 3,
                "type": "Float32Array",
                "binary": true
            }
        },
        "index": {
            "array": "AAAAAAEAAAACAAAAAAAAAAMAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAUAAAAGAAAAAAAAAAcAAAAIAAAAAgAAAAUAAAAI\r\nAAAACAAAAAMAAAACAAAACQAAAAoAAAALAAAACwAAAAwAAAAJAAAACQAAAA0AAAAOAAAACQAAAA8A\r\n",
            "itemSize": 1,
            "type": "Uint32Array",
            "binary": true
        }
    },
    "type": "BufferGeometry",
    "name": "bird_geometry.001"
}
```

I want to edit this object, but I can't make a buffered object like in the source code. How can I decode usual geometry to `Float23Array` and `Uint32Array` buffering? I was searching for some days and didn't get any example or way to solve it.

I need to use BufferGeometry (not usual Geometry) because the script inputs this type. I need to make a buffered object from usual x,y,z points.

How can I do this?

Comment: If you want to get a buffer geometry from a usual one, then you can use `.fromGeometry()` method of `THREE.BufferGeometry()`, like: `var bufGeom = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry( usualGeom );`, where `usualGeom` is a usual geometry. Read about [`THREE.BufferGeometry()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/BufferGeometry).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I was trying to do this solution but i can't get the buffered array as output of this method. It gives object without array like in my example (type of Float32Array).
I was trying to search for compiler geometry > buffer and still no results.
Need to generate buffergeom like in my example.